# How to know all available models in an SAPUI5 application?

Tags: model, sapui5

While trying to debug a big complex application, I came across that there are plenty of models created in it for different purposes.

Apart from the fact that this is a wrong approach of coding, I am trying to find how can I know the list of all models that are made available to the application.

Any useful methods?

Comment: out of curiosity, could you elaborate on why using multiple models is a wrong approach of coding? I often do it to enhance readability

Comment: Except, it reduces the code readability. As many models are used, they can be set, reset in multiple places. Also, as per Fiori best practices, limiting the models to as less as 1 is the best way to approach the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve all models bound to your view, you could use 
`this.getView().oModels` to see all existing models for that view.

I don't know of a way to retrieve all models used in your application, but I assume that in order to debug your issue, you at least have access to the View on where your bug is located.

Answer (score 2):

To see all models available to the control, use the following:

```
Object.assign({}, control.oModels, control.oPropagatedProperties.oModels)
```

To log all models created during app lifetime, one can monkey-patch the `sap.ui.model.Model` constructor and add logging capabilities there.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the UI5 chrome add-on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ui5-inspector/bebecogbafbighhaildooiibipcnbngo

By the way, it is not the wrong approach to have multiple models.